# running multiple execve functions in one c++ file

Tags: c++, command, system, wc, execve

I have to write a `c++` program which "counts the number of lines, words and the number of bytes from a text file", all of which must be in a new line.

I have to use the wc command in my c++ program. I have managed to get the number of lines:

```
char *envp[] = {NULL};
char *command[] = {"wc", "-l", filename.c_str(), NULL};
execve("/usr/bin/wc", command, envp);
```

After the above statements, I have one which replaces "-l" with "-w" and so forth. But my program ends immediately after the first `execve()` statement.

How do I get all my statements to execute even after the `execve()` statement?

N.B: This will be my first time running system commands using a c++ program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `char *command[] = {"wc", "-l", filename.c_str(), NULL};` is not a valid initialization, "wc" could be a `char const *`, but not `char *`

Comment: I've performed a type cast within the array (char *)"wc". I decided to leave out all my type casts from the code because they're not what I'm having trouble with

Comment: That type cast is not valid either because strings command pointers point to must be modifiable.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) -or something newer- then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and related `man` pages. Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) for a good overview about OSes.

Comment: thank you for the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execve` replaces current executable image with a specified one and therefore never returns upon success. If you want to continue executing main program then you will need to `fork` first. Or use something as dull as `system` function.

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned I'm relatively new to this, I'll do some research about fork(). Thank you.